# How to deploy a web application Aurelia in an Apache server?

Tags: javascript, apache, aurelia

To try, I used the latest "aurelia-skeleton-navigation 1.0.0-beta.1.0.1".

To deploy the Aurelia web application in an Apache server I used "gulp export"  command and I copied the contents of the "export" in the "www/html/myapp" directory !

So, the welcome tab works fine, but not the "github users" tab !

The error is :

> ERROR [app-router] Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost/myapp/jspm_packages/github/github/fetch@0.10.1.js
>       Error loading http://localhost/myapp/jspm_packages/github/github/fetch@0.10.1.js as "github:github/fetch@0.10.1" from http://localhost/myapp/dist/users.js
>   Stack trace:
>   o@http://localhost/myapp/jspm_packages/system.js:4:12750
>   e/http://localhost/myapp/jspm_packages/system.js:4:13275

what have I missed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message I can say that the `fetch` polyfill is missing from the exported folder.

To fix that, edit the file `build/export.json`. Replace the lines

```
"jspm_packages/github/github/fetch@0.9.0.js",
"jspm_packages/github/github/fetch@0.9.0/fetch.js"
```

with references to the correct version (0.10.1 in your case):

```
"jspm_packages/github/github/fetch@0.10.1.js",
"jspm_packages/github/github/fetch@0.10.1/fetch.js"
```

Then run the `gulp export` command again and make sure that `fetch` files are now copied into `jspm_packages`.

There is already [a pull request to fix that](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/pull/215/commits).