# Installing an Aurelia web application on a web server other than ones for the turorial

Tags: javascript, apache, aurelia

I am studying Aurelia following the starter kit. In detail, I have selected the option of TypeScript and I complie them in Visual studio 2015. At present, the example applications work well on the local web server, IIS. Now I want to test it on an internet web server where I usually put my static html files and some php and ruby pages. Probably, the server is an apache managed by some IT company.

As I am very new to this field, I just plan to put the top folder of the local file system together with its all sub folders into somewhere in the web file system of the internet server.
Then the question is, will it work normally? I feel other options are too complexed for me to achieve at present. Or is there other simple alternative way?

I read [a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34000039/how-to-deploy-a-web-application-aurelia-in-an-apache-server), but the anwer instruction is to difficult for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.2.4/doc/article/bundling-your-app-for-deploy teaches how to bundle your app for deployment. In short, it will transform your app in a couple files (usually 1 .html and 2 .js).

To bundle your app, run `gulp export`. It will create an "export" folder inside the application folder. Then, just copy and paste those files in the server and the app will work normally.